# How to sort the data in Amazon dynamodb using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sorting, amazon-dynamodb

How to sort the `countryCode` column data in ascending order or descending order in amazon dynamodb using java

How to use `SortOrder enum` in code.

`SortOrder` enum is available in package`com.amazonaws.services.codedeploy.model.SortOrder`.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "cd_country")
public class Country implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5698425418072128936L;

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String countryId;

    private String countryCode;

    private String countryName;

    private Long isActive;

    public String getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public Long getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Long isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `com.amazonaws.services.codedeploy.model.SortOrder` would be used for DynamoDB? The AWS SDK is essentially split up per service.

Comment: @MikeKobit In `SortOrder` class it contains `Ascending("ascending"),
    Descending("descending");`. Can you tell me how to sort `countryCode` column data in ascending / descending order in java.

Comment: `SortOrder` is specific to [AWS CodyDeploy](http://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/). You need to use the `Scan` operation to read the entire table and pull the results into memory where you will have to sort it, as I said in my answer. Another option would be to use [DynamoDB Online Indexing announced yesterday](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-update-online-indexing-reserved-capacity-improvements/) to create an index on the table, and then you can use the `Query` operation to fetch the ordered results and you can paginate through without having to read the entire table first.

Comment: @MikeKobit Can you post a code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort the `countryCode` since there is not an [index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) on it. You will have to use a [`Scan`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html) to fetch all the rows and sort the data in your application.

Side note: `countryCode` is not a column in DynamoDB - it is an attribute. See the [DynamoDB DataModel](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html) for more information.